# How do I get VBA to recognize "001" for my loop?

Tags: string, vba, loops, integer

I'm making a basic loop as follows:

```
Sub IntegerTestforSuffixFinder()

Dim i As Double

i = 1
MsgBox (i)

    Do While i < 100
i = i + 1
    If vbOK Then
MsgBox (i)
    Else: End
    End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

This works just fine...but would I really need it to do for the actual problem I'm about to tackle is recognize i = 001. The zeroes are important place holders in this context, but it keeps correcting me to i = 1. Is there a way to stop this?

Much thanks!

Comment: Convert the *integer* to a *string* following a prescribed format. *Integers* do not have leading zeros.

Comment: Numbers are numbers; leading zeroes are completely meaningless.

Comment: I don't use VBA, but it looks like - Excel, anyway - provides a [Format](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/format_string.php), which *might* be used something like `Format(CStr(i), "000")`

Comment: Oh, that was silly of me. Okay so now it can display "001" then continues on to 2, 3, 4, 5. Is there a way to set it up to add it like you would integers rather than strings...? I know that it's recognizing it as characters instead of integers which is WHY it won't do the math, but can it be done another way?

Comment: @meer2kat The `i` variable should *always* represent an integer and thus it will always "add like an integer"; it is only that `strOfI = ToStringWithSpecificFormat(i)` should be a string. Then `MsgBox(strOfI)` or `MsgBox(ToStringWithSpecificFormat(i))` - maybe the conversion wasn't added for *both* message boxes?

Comment: Hmmm I was looking at that. I will try it more tomorrow morning. No luck so far, but what you're saying makes a lot of sense! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't.  And you can't.  But you **can** use the original Integer in your loop, and create a string that you can display.  Try this and see if you can pull what you need from it:

```
Sub IntegerTestforSuffixFinder()

Dim i As Double

i = 1
MsgBox (i)

    Do While i < 100
    i = i + 1
    If vbOK Then
       'Original integer
       MsgBox (i)
       '3-character string created by using the Right() function
       MsgBox Right("000" & i, 3)
    Else: End
    End If

    Loop

End Sub
```

BTW, in your original example you realize you're starting your MsgBox at 2?  You set i = 1, then you're adding 1 to it before displaying the first MsgBox.  I'm thinking you probably want to move that **i = i + 1** line to just before the Loop.

Comment: Works perfectly! I just removed "MsgBox (i)" and i = 1. Thanks so much! Works great!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:
Format cell - Custom.  Look for Type with a "0".  Type three "0" as below:

[image]

The value remains as integer.

Comment: @meer2kat Oh ok, there you found a solution from Johnny